# docker network not working without link

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, docker-network

I have a `mysql` container and a `service` container that needs to connect to the `mysql` container.

I created a networking with `docker network create chrisbolton`

I am spinning up the `mysql` container with

`docker run --name chrisbolton-mysql -v /Users/Bolton/chrisbolton-data:/var/lib/mysql --network chrisbolton -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=chrisbolton -d mysql:latest`

I am spinning up the `service` container with

`docker run -p 8080:8080 --name chrisbolton-service --network chrisbolton --link chrisbolton-mysql:mysql -d chrisbolton-service`

However, I know that `link` is deprecated and I need to move to only using `networks`. But if I remove the `link` here the two containers cannot communicate.

I am connecting to `mysql` with the following config:

```
#disbale Spring banner
spring.main.banner-mode=off

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/chrisbolton
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have done a `docker network inspect chrisbolton` to get the IPAddresses and have tried changing my config file to point to that directly. But still not sure why it won't connect.

Comment: `datasource.url` is not correct, you should specify the name of the container to which you want to connect. And later you will know that there are better options than using the name of service.

Comment: so `datasource.url` needs to be `jdbc:mysql://chrisbolton-mysql:3306/chrisbolton`?

Comment: Yes, this should work. Did you try?

Comment: @Ayushya that worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datasource.url` is not correct, you should specify the name of the container to which you want to connect. There are better options than using the name of service. You can use [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) or [hostname](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).

While in this case, as you indicated in comments, `datasource.url` needs to be `jdbc:mysql://chrisbolton-mysql:3306/chrisbolton`